# How to find row number from content of cell in python?

Tags: python, pandas, database, csv

How do I from a specific ticker in a cell parse out where that specific ticker occurs? For example if I'm looking for 'AAAB' I would get a read back of every row number that has 'AAAB' Is it better to use pandas or CSV to do this?

```
    ,ticker
    472,AA
    473,AA
    474,AAAB
    475,AAAB
    476,AAAB
    477,AAAB
    478,AAAB
    479,AAAB
    480,AAAB
    481,AAAB
    482,AAAB
    483,AAAB
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the number of the rows that match the desired pattern, you can use `pandas`. If your data is inside a `.csv` file, you can just do:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'my_file.csv'
pattern = 'AAAB'

df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)

rows = df[df['ticker'] == pattern].index.to_list()
```

This will give you the corresponding list of row numbers:

```
[474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483]
```

Comment: I just realize when I do this I get an error. It says KeyError. I'm pretty sure key errors arise when you have the wrong column labels? Any advice?

Comment: What is the entire error message?

Comment: It's too long to post. I'll just make another question

Comment: this is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64922470/cant-figure-out-why-i-keep-getting-a-keyerror-while-trying-to-the-number-of-a-c

Comment: Just remove the `index_col` and it should be fine. The command should be just `pd.read_csv(filename)`